# Yum update crashes

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum, amazon-linux

I am trying to run `yum update` on my Amazon-Linux-2 Workspace. It crashes with the following output

```
❯ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: amzn_workspaces_filter_updates, halt_os_update_check, priorities, update-motd
357 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package snap-confine.x86_64 0:2.36.3-0.amzn2 will be updated
---> Package snap-confine.x86_64 0:2.55.3-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package snapd.x86_64 0:2.36.3-0.amzn2 will be updated
---> Package snapd.x86_64 0:2.55.3-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: snapd-selinux = 2.55.3-1.el7 for package: snapd-2.55.3-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: squashfuse for package: snapd-2.55.3-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package snapd-selinux.noarch 0:2.55.3-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: policycoreutils-python for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
---> Package squashfuse.x86_64 0:0.1.102-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: squashfuse-libs(x86-64) = 0.1.102-1.el7 for package: squashfuse-0.1.102-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfuseprivate.so.0()(64bit) for package: squashfuse-0.1.102-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsquashfuse.so.0()(64bit) for package: squashfuse-0.1.102-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzstd.so.1()(64bit) for package: squashfuse-0.1.102-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzstd.x86_64 0:1.5.2-1.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.5-22.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: setools-libs >= 3.3.8-2 for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsemanage-python >= 2.5-9 for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: audit-libs-python >= 2.1.3-4 for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-IPy for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-python for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1(VERS_1.4)(64bit) for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1(VERS_1.2)(64bit) for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapol.so.4(VERS_4.0)(64bit) for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: checkpolicy for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1()(64bit) for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapol.so.4()(64bit) for package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.amzn2.x86_64
---> Package snapd-selinux.noarch 0:2.55.3-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
---> Package squashfuse-libs.x86_64 0:0.1.102-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.8.1-3.amzn2.1 will be installed
---> Package checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-6.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.5-12.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-11.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package python-IPy.noarch 0:0.75-6.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
---> Package setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.8-2.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package snapd-selinux.noarch 0:2.55.3-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.55.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried `yum clean all` and

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm –rebuilddb
yum clean all
yum update
```

I still get the same error.
What would be the best way to fix this? Or how can I figure out what is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ran `yum update --skip-broken` followed by a regular `yum update`
and through that, I was able to narrow the offending package to snap.

Doing `yum uninstall snapd` fixed the problem.